# Can TypeScript be used with existing JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, migration

I am working on pretty big existing web application with team. Time to time we experience common JavaScript coding nuances like case difference while function calling or missing operator etc.

I find TypeScript promising solution for such issues specially while working with team on different files/modules. It has many benefits like

- Static code analysis
- Better auto-completion
- Code Minification
- Dead Code Reduction
- String Type Checking
- Strict OOP

I know there are converters available which can convert JavaScript to typescript but I do not want to convert existing project files to TypeScript.

I was wondering if it is possible to keep existing code as is and develop new modules/files in TypeScript. May be we can migrate existing files in gradual manner.

Will they work well together? How to do it?

I have tried to read online but couldn't find much relevant information other than converting existing projects to TypeScript.

Comment: You have to compile TypeScript to JavaScript anyway, just include the transform stage in your build process?  If you have a large existing codebase I would keep .ts code somewhat separate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
From [the language spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md) :

> TypeScript is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript. TypeScript syntax is a
>   superset of ECMAScript 6 (ES6) syntax.
>
> Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program. The TypeScript compiler performs only file-local
>   transformations on TypeScript programs and does not re-order variables
>   declared in TypeScript. This leads to JavaScript output that closely
>   matches the TypeScript input. TypeScript does not transform variable
>   names, making tractable the direct debugging of emitted JavaScript.
>   TypeScript optionally provides source maps, enabling source-level
>   debugging. TypeScript tools typically emit JavaScript upon file save,
>   preserving the test, edit, refresh cycle commonly used in JavaScript
>   development.